# Sequelize CLI migration error "Cannot read property 'type' of undefined" when creating table with db:migrate

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm running `yarn sequelize db:migrate` to create the table in the database using a postgres image in the docker and returns the following message:

```
mateus @ fariasmateuss: ~ / Projects / gobarber / server $ yarn sequelize db: migrate
yarn run v1.22.4

$ /home/mateus/Projects/gobarber/server/node_modules/.bin/sequelize db: migrate

Sequelize CLI [Node: 12.17.0, CLI: 6.0.0, ORM: 6.2.0]

Loaded configuration file "src / config / database.js".
== 20200627041347-create-users: migrating =======

ERROR: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command
```

Configuration of the `.sequelizerc` file:

```
const {resolve} = require ('path');

module.exports = {
  config: resolves (__ dirname, 'src', 'config', 'database.js'),
  'models-path': resolves (__ dirname, 'src', 'app', 'models'),
  'migrations-path': resolves (__ dirname, 'src', 'database', 'migrations'),
  'seeders-path': resolves (__ dirname, 'src', 'database', 'seeds'),
};
```

Code to create the table in the file `migrations.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable ('users', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
      },
      password_hash: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      provider: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValues: false,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      created_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATA,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      updated_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATA,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    });
  },

  down: (queryInterface) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable ('users');
  },
};
```

> OS: Linux Focal Fossa 20.04 LTS

Would anyone know what the possible solution would be?

Comment: Code you can see here https://github.com/fariasmateuss/gobarber

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error seems to be a typo, the `type` for `Sequelize.DATA` vs `Sequelize.DATE`.

Here are the valid data types.

https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/data-types.html

Comment: I got this error by a similar typo in a migration name: {
                type: Sequelize.STING}, which should have been STRING